# Averroes's commentaries on Aristotle

Tags: reference-request, aristotle

Are the commentaries of Averroes, in Latin or English translation, available online? If there are none available online, what are some editions of Averroes in Latin or English?

The closest I've been able to find is [this](https://www.sydneypenner.ca/os/aristotle.shtml), but they are very hard-to-read and old editions. Are there OCRed or recently-published editions available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Sydney Penner's "Averroes (and Aristotle)" page](https://www.sydneypenner.ca/os/aristotle.shtml):

- *Aristotelis opera cum Averrois commentariis*. Venice: Junctas, 1562. [vol. 1](http://gallica2.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k58709z) / [vol. 2](http://gallica2.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k587105) / [vol. 3](http://gallica2.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k58711h) / [vol. 4](http://gallica2.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k58712v) / vol. 5 - NA / [vol. 6](http://gallica2.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k58715w) / [vol. 7](http://gallica2.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k587167) / [vol. 8](http://gallica2.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k58717k) / [vol. 9](http://gallica2.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k58718x).

HathTrust has some nicer scans of the above, all volumes 1-9 (complete):

- Aristotle, Averroës, Levi ben Gershom, Jacob Mantino, Bernardino Tomitano, Marco Antonio Zimara, and Aristotle. 1962. [*Aristotelis opera cum Averrois commentariis*](https://catalog.hathitrust.org/api/volumes/oclc/14622157.html). Venetiis: Apud Junctas.

Answer (score 2):

Try :

On Aristotle's "Metaphysics". An Annotated Translation of the So-called "Epitome"
Ed. by Arnzen, Rüdiger (2010):

eBook (PDF) ISBN 978-3-11-022002-5

Hardcover : ISBN 978-3-11-022001-8

Charles E. Butterworth (translator), Averroes's commentaries on Aristotle, Averroes' Middle Commentaries on Aristotle's Categories and De Interpretatione. Published by Princeton University Press, New Jersey, 1983.

Charles E. Butterworth (translator), Averroes' Three Short Commentaries on Aristotle's "Topics," "Rhetoric," and "Poetics", Published by State University of New York Press, Albany, 1977.

Charles E. Butterworth (translator), Averroes' Middle Commentary on Aristotle's "Poetics, ISBN 10: 0691073023 / ISBN 13: 9780691073026
Published by Princeton University Press, 1986.

Comment: @Geremia. Suggested modern translations of the Commentaries. Can't find anything helpful online. Best : GLT

Comment: What about his commentary on Aristotle's _Physics_?

Comment: Is [_Averroes’ Questions in Physics_](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-94-009-2151-1) ed. by Helen Tunik Goldstein his commentary on Aristotle's _Physics_?